# Moving Data from Matrix A to Matrix B in R

Tags: r, matrix, replace, copy

I want to cut/move/replace some data (to be precise 2500) from Matrix A to Matrix B in R.

for example Move cell(i,j) from matrix A to cell(i,j) in matrix B. both i and j have some fixed value(50 to be precise) and replace that cell(i,j) in matrix A with "0".

Since I am newto programming can anyone help me with the coding?

Thanks in Advance
Regards

Comment: Please provide small example datasets and expected result

Comment: let matrix A= 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
matrix B =
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
After replacing cell (2,2) in matrix A with "0" output should be
matrix A=
1 2 3
4 0 6
7 8 9
matrix B=
0 0 0
0 5 0
0 0 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first define a two column coordinate-matrix of the values you want to replace, where the first column refers is the row-index and the second column is the column-index. As an example, suppose you want to replace the cells `c(2,1)`, `c(2,2)` and `c(1,2)` in a `3x3` matrix `B` with the calues from a `3x3` matrix `A`:

```
ind <- cbind(c(2,2,1), c(1,2,2))
A <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
B <- matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = 3)

B[ind] <- A[ind]; A[ind] <- 0
B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    4   NA
[2,]    2    5   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    7
[2,]    0    0    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Comment: i used the following code but it is not working

D = read.csv(file="C:/Ashique/Work/Prof Keppo/Expotential/Distance Matrix.csv",header=FALSE)
X = read.csv(file="C:/Ashique/Work/Prof Keppo/50densecounty.csv",header=FALSE)
Y = read.csv(file="C:/Ashique/Work/Prof Keppo/50densecounty.csv",header=FALSE)


###########Creating D Large###########
D_large = matrix(data=0,nrow=2377,ncol=2377)

for(i in 1:50)
{
  for(j in 1:50)
  {
    D_large[X[i,1],(Y[i,1])] = D[X[i,1],(Y[i,1])]
  }
}
write.csv(D_large,file="C:/Ashique/Work/Prof Keppo/Dual Discount/D_large.csv" )

Comment: What error do you get? Where are you using you second index `j`?